# Display and manipulate Visio diagram (.vsdx) over the web

Tags: c#, .net, visio, office-2016

I have a customer with a rather complex diagram that they've created using Visio 2016, and they are asking if it is possible to

1) View the diagram over the internet, and
2) Manipulate the diagram over the internet

I have found that #1 is easy to do, as Visio allows you to save a diagram as .htm, and then generates numerous files accordingly.

However, #2 has me stumped. I've spent around 2 hours searching the internet, but haven't arrived at any clear conclusions as to how to do this.

With regards to manipulating the diagram, they simply wish to change the state of certain shapes to "on" and "off". The state is indicated by the background color and/or orientation of the shape.

Is this possible to do using C# web forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at my extension. It allows you to export Visio diagram as SVG, which is relatively easy to manipulate / animate.

In Visio, you can assign ids or classes to shapes, and then in javascript you can use those to manipulate the shapes (with d3 or jquery for example)

Check out the samples:
http://unmanagedvisio.com/html-export-demo/

Comment: Thanks a ton!! This will work for what I need to do!